# Need java code for chat program in wireless network

Tags: java, sockets, udp, chat, wireless

I have been written chat program code for wired network.
I want to write the chat code in java for wireless network.I googled it for this.But i can't found that.So please guide me to write the chat code in java for wireless networks in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you're implementing the network stack yourself this shouldn't make any difference.  Just open a network connection as normal and let the OS worry about what interfaces to use to get the packets to their destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a chat program on a wireless network is not different from creating a chat program on any network. Normaly, you don't have to handle layers that deep in the network stack.
So basically, what you are looking for is infos about how to create a chat program in Java. Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to create your own chat protocol or implement an existing protocole, like XMPP (the protocol behind Jabber and Google Talk)? The first possibility is a bit complicated and kind of pointless outside an academic context, so I go with the second. You can look at libraries letting you use XMPP in Java, like Smack:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 5):

The reason why do didn't find anything on Google is probably because it's **no different from working with a wired network**. The type of medium used for network communication lies on a lower level than your Java application is suppose to care about.